# Proper way to store tab states in Compose Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

What is the proper way to store tab content state in Compose Multiplatform? "Remember" keeps state only during recompositions, not when one view replaces another. On Android ViewModel should be used, but in Compose Multiplatform there is no ViewModel class.

Comment: I keep the state outside the compose-ui tree. You can have a State class that have children states where each child state correspond to a tab state.
Eg: https://github.com/pablichjenkov/uistate3/blob/f8de9ec8093cd75085dce4a12ef26e4ea209e553/node/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/pablichj/encubator/node/navbar/NavBarNode.kt#L26
In this example I use a State Holder class named NavBarNode that contains child Nodes for each tab. 
That mechanism goes all the way to the root  state Node that lives outside the compose-ui tree. Could live in an Activity ViewModel or in a Singleton.